# How to create a constraint in an XML Schema what requires the value of one node to be greater than a previous node of the same type?

Tags: xml, xpath, schema

I have an XML instance document of in the following format:

```
<Location>
   <LocationPoint>
      <XLoc>0.00</XLoc>
      <OtherData>XYZ</OtherData>
   </LocationPoint>
   <LocationPoint>
      <XLoc>10.00</XLoc>
      <OtherData>ABC</OtherData>
   </LocationPoint>
   <LocationPoint>
      <XLoc>20.00</XLoc>
      <OtherData>QRS</OtherData>
   </LocationPoint>
</Location>
```

How do I write schema code that forces each succesive Xloc value to be greater than the previous one?

I've tried to apply a restriction on XLoc with the minExclusive facet being an XPath exression, but it either doesn't work or I've got the syntax all messed up (see below).

```
<xs:element name="XLoc">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
         <xs:minExclusive value="parent/preceding-sibling/XLoc" />
      </xs:restriction></xs:simpleType></xs:element>
```

Any ideas, solutions, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do it with XML schema 1.1 and [Type Alternatives](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative).